# Bootstrap not working at all, I don't understand why

Tags: css

```
   <!DOCTYPE HTML>
   <html>
   <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">


    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">


    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container-fluid">
        <p>akdsjfhalsdhjflashdfklasjhdfkljashdfakdsjfhalsdhjflashdfklasjhdfkljashdfakdsjfhalsdhjflashdfklasjhdfkljashdf
            akdsjfhalsdhjflashdfklasjhdfkljashdfakdsjfhalsdhjflashdfklasjhdfkljashdfakdsjfhalsdhjflashdfklasjhdfkljashdf
            akdsjfhalsdhjflashdfklasjhdfkljashdfakdsjfhalsdhjflashdfklasjhdfkljashdfakdsjfhalsdhjflashdfklasjhdfkljashdf
            akdsjfhalsdhjflashdfklasjhdfkljashdfakdsjfhalsdhjflashdfklasjhdfkljashdfakdsjfhalsdhjflashdfklasjhdfkljashdf
            akdsjfhalsdhjflashdfklasjhdfkljashdf</p>

        <p>akdsjfhalsdhjflashdfklasjhdfkljashdfakdsjfhalsdhjflashdfklasjhdfkljashdfakdsjfhalsdhjflashdfklasjhdfkljashdf
            akdsjfhalsdhjflashdfklasjhdfkljashdfakdsjfhalsdhjflashdfklasjhdfkljashdfakdsjfhalsdhjflashdfklasjhdfkljashdf
            akdsjfhalsdhjflashdfklasjhdfkljashdfakdsjfhalsdhjflashdfklasjhdfkljashdfakdsjfhalsdhjflashdfklasjhdfkljashdf
            akdsjfhalsdhjflashdfklasjhdfkljashdfakdsjfhalsdhjflashdfklasjhdfkljashdfakdsjfhalsdhjflashdfklasjhdfkljashdf
            akdsjfhalsdhjflashdfklasjhdfkljashdf</p>
         </div>
        <button class"btn btn-success" onclick="$(this).hide();"> Click Me!    </button>

         <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script    src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/myscript.js"></script>
        </body>
      </html>
```

This is the code thats not working. Could you guys please help me out. when i resize the screen nothing happens. Any help is appreciated

Comment: what are you expecting?

Comment: What are you expecting when you re-size the screen...you've barely used Bootstrap at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is working.

You could see the button styled in the bootstrap fashion if you fix the *HTML*. Instead of:

```
 <button class"btn btn-success" onclick="$(this).hide();"> Click Me!    </button>
```

You should write:

```
 <button class="btn btn-success" onclick="$(this).hide();">Click Me!</button>
```

You are missing the "=" symbol after the `class` keyword.

Regarding the `content-fluid` class, the only thing it does is to add the *CSS* to the element:

```
padding-right: 15px;
padding-left: 15px;
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
```

So you will hardly notice any change when you resize the window.

Answer (score 0):

If you are writing the code in your local environment, could you please make sure that your internet is working and the URL is not blocked,

> `https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css`

because you are taking the css from a hosted location, so if that URL is inaccessible, the code would not work.

If in doubt, try to refer the bootstrap css from your local disk.